# Java. Множество Set удалить элементы

Tags: java

Почему подчеркивает параметр передаваемый в метод `removeAllNumbersMoreThan10`?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.*;

public class DeletMoreThan10 {

    /* Удалить все числа больше 10
Создать множество чисел(Set<Integer>), занести туда 20 различных чисел.
Удалить из множества все числа больше 10.
*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Integer> beginset = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            beginset.add((int)(Math.random()*100));
        }

        for (Integer i : beginset) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        Set<Integer> endset = new HashSet<>();

            endset = removeAllNumbersMoreThan10(beginset);

        for (Integer i : endnset) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

            }

        public static HashSet<Integer> removeAllNumbersMoreThan10(HashSet<Integer> set)
        {
            Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
            while ( iterator.hasNext())
            {
                Integer number = iterator.next();
                if (number > 10)
                    iterator.remove();
            }
            return (HashSet)set;
        }
```

Comment: А что пишет если навести курсором мышки на подчеркнутый красным параметр? Хотя я и так представляю. Смотрите, в `removeAllNumbersMoreThan10` вместо `HashSet` передавайте парамеметр как тип `Set` или приводите к типу `HashSet` -> `removeAllNumbersMoreThan10((HashSet) beginset);` или `beginset` объявите как `HashSet`

Comment: Спасибо. Работает если привести передаваемый параметр к HashSet. Если вместо HashSet передавать параметр как тип Set, то остаются числа меньше 10. Может есть какая-то ссылка под рукой, где почитать про Set, HashSet.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html и смотрите там "All Known Implementing Classes:"

Answer (score 2):

> Почему подчеркивает параметр передаваемый в метод `removeAllNumbersMoreThan10`?

Потому что метод принимает `HashSet`, а вы передаете `Set`. Правильно - изменить тип аргумента метода на интерфейс - его логика никак не зависит от конкретной реализации `Set`-а.

> ```
> Set<Integer> endset = new HashSet<>();
> endset = removeAllNumbersMoreThan10(beginset);
> ```

Метод `removeAllNumbersMoreThan10` удаляет элементы из первоначального `Set`-a и поэтому `endset` и `beginset` - это один и тот же объект. Поэтому вы можете сделать `void removeAllNumbersMoreThan10` и работать после удаления с `beginset`, т.е.:

```
for (Integer i : beginset) {
    System.out.println(i);
}

removeAllNumbersMoreThan10(beginset);

for (Integer i : beginset) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

**PS:** при использовании Java 8 удаление можно сделать в одну строку:

```
beginset.removeIf(value -> value > 10);
```

а вывод в консоль:

```
beginset.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Очень удобно удалять в одну строчку.

Comment: Я так понимаю у коллекции Map нет метода removeIf?

Comment: @АнтонЕфимов `map.entrySet().removeIf(e -> e.getKey() > 10)`

Comment: Спасибо, лямбда выражения еще не изучал.